# find-tag M-. vs Windows 10 emoji

Tags: key-bindings, microsoft-windows

Recent Windows update kills my M-. (Meta-dot) binding, it intercept the keystroke (Windows Key+.) and display the emoji windows.
I already try this link
https://techcult.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-emoji-panel-in-windows-10/
but not working (can't find the EnableExpressiveInputShellHotkey key)
Any of you got the solution?
Thanks

Comment: I suspect this question may be a duplicate. Please search for tag `microsoft-windows` to see if you find it.

Comment: Thanks @Dan for finding the dup.